# Refresh enhaced grid preserving client side filter

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

How can we refresh enhanced grid after a filter in applied, preserving the filter query??
doing grid.setFilter() clears the filter. Is there any way to access all active filters in grid to give like grid.setFilter(activefilters)?????

Answer (score 2):

hmm..... i got the answer myself,

its grid.getFilter() which gives the current filters

grid.setFilter(grid.getFilter());

refreshes the grid with current filters..

that simple it was :)